# SQL Group By question SQL Server 2005 CE

Tags: sql-server-2005, compact-framework, group-by

I'm having a problem with an sql query that i use for my mobile application which uses sql server 2005 ce. I'm not so good with t-sql, so have a problem with this query

```
SELECT TP.ID_TASK_MASTER, TP.ID_PROBLEM, TP.ID_TASK_PROBLE, P.DS_PROBLEM, 
       TP.SW_HASOK, TP.SW_HASNOK, TP.SW_HASTOK, TP.SW_HASVALUE,  
       TP.NO_VALUE1, TP.NO_VALUE2 
FROM TASK_PROBLEMS TP 
  INNER JOIN PROBLEMS P 
    ON TP.ID_PROBLEM = P.ID_PROBLEM  
GROUP BY P.DS_PROBLEM,TP.ID_TASK_MASTER, TP.ID_PROBLEM, TP.ID_TASK_PROBLE 
HAVING TP.ID_TASK_MASTER = @P_IDTASKMASTER
```

What i try to do is doing a group by on ds_problem field, getting an error like this :

{"In aggregate and grouping expressions, the SELECT clause can contain only aggregates and grouping expressions. [ Select clause = TP,SW_HASOK ]"}

So what i made wrong? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I suppose what you meant to do was

```
SELECT TP.ID_TASK_MASTER, TP.ID_PROBLEM, TP.ID_TASK_PROBLE, P.DS_PROBLEM, 
       TP.SW_HASOK, TP.SW_HASNOK, TP.SW_HASTOK, TP.SW_HASVALUE,  
       TP.NO_VALUE1, TP.NO_VALUE2 
FROM TASK_PROBLEMS TP 
  INNER JOIN PROBLEMS P 
    ON TP.ID_PROBLEM = P.ID_PROBLEM  
WHERE TP.ID_TASK_MASTER = @P_IDTASKMASTER
ORDER BY P.DS_PROBLEM,TP.ID_TASK_MASTER, TP.ID_PROBLEM,TP.ID_TASK_PROBLE
```